# Get-AzKeyVaultSecret - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I can list all the Keyvaults from the current subscription, but when I try to use Get-AzKeyVault I get the following error:

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "KV-PROJECT"
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

Same error happens when I try to set a new secret

```
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "KV-PROJECT" -Name "test" -SecretValue $value
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I am running Powershell 7.3.3 on my corporate laptop and have been using many of the Az module cmdlets without issues.

Based on what I have found so far, the error seems to be related to a network access. Could it be the Azure firewall is blocking access to the keyvaults for some reason?